# When a $A$ commute with $e^B$, does it also commute $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, exponential-function, matrix-exponential

Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices, and let $[A,B]=AB-BA$ be the commutator of $A$ and $B$.

Then, if we consider the matrix exponential $e^B=\sum_n \frac{B^n}{n!} $, we have
$$ [A,e^B]=\sum_n \frac{1}{n!}[A,B^n] $$

Now, if $[A,B]=0$, then $[A,B^n]=0$ $\forall n$ and therefore $[A,e^B]=0$. But what about the converse? Is it true as well?

In other words, does $[A,e^B]=0$ imply $[A,B]=0$ ?

Answer (score 6):

No. E.g. let $B=\pmatrix{0&0\\ 0&2\pi i}$. Then $e^B=I$. Now, all matrices commute with $e^B$, but some of them don't commute with $B$.

More generally, if $B$ is diagonalisable over $\mathbb C$ and it possesses two eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ such that $\lambda_1-\lambda_2$ is a *nonzero* integer multiple of $2\pi i$ (i.e. $B$ is a diagonalisable matrix whose eigenvalues are *not* $2\pi i$ congruence-free), then the family of matrices that commute with $B$ is a proper subset of the family of matrices that commute with $e^B$. Hence this $B$ serves as a counterexample to your hypothesis. In particular, any such counterexample must be non-Hermitian.

Comment: Indeed $B^2=2\pi iB$, so$$e^B-I_2=\underbrace{\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{(2\pi i)^n}{n!}}_{e^{2\pi i}-1=0}\frac{B}{2\pi i}=O.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! I wonder if the only case in which something like this can happen is when the matrices are non-Hermitian, or if this is more general.

Comment: @kenobi Yes, any such counterexample must be non-Hermitian. If $B$ is Hermitian, we may, by a change of orthonormal basis, assume that $B=\bigoplus_{k=1}^r\lambda_kI_{m_k}$ where the $\lambda_k$s are distinct real numbers. Since the exponential function is injective on the real line, $B=\bigoplus_{k=1}^r\mu_kI_{m_k}$ where the $\mu_k$s (which are equal to $e^{\lambda_k}$) are distinct. Thus the family of matrices that commute with $B$, namely the set of matrices in the form of $\bigoplus_{k=1}^rX_k$ where $X_k$ is $m_k\times m_k$, is the same as the family of matrices that commute with $e^B$.